# Setting up Virtual Hosts on Mac with different subdirectories

Tags: macos, apache, mamp, virtual-hosts

I have problems setting up my local development environment on a mac.

What i have (added):

/private/etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1       dev.local
127.0.0.1       page1.dev.local
```

/Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost dev.local:8888>
    ServerName dev.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/user1/Sites/
    <Directory /Users/user1/Sites/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost page1.dev.local:8888>
    ServerName page1.dev.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/user1/Sites/page1/
    <Directory /Users/user1/Sites/page1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Basically I would like to have a "root" accessible via http://dev.local and physically at  /Users/user1/Sites

The first project (page1) accessible via http://page1.dev.local and located at /Users/user1/Sites/page1

The next projects follow the same logic.

When I open http://dev.local I see the correct page but with http://page1.dev.local I get the same page.

I always restart Apache of course!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution which works: I have to insert a `ServerAlias` and add an asterix after `VirtualHost`

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName dev.local
    ServerAlias dev.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/user1/Sites/
    <Directory /Users/user1/Sites/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8888>
    ServerName page1.dev.local
    ServerAlias page1.dev.local
    DocumentRoot /Users/user1/Sites/page1/
    <Directory /Users/user1/Sites/page1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```